# How do I kill the player in Minecraft when they enter a specific area (-131 5 236 to -122 5 227)?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-commands, minecraft-redstone

Am making a minigame where the player dies when they fall and I need to kill them without destroying items. I don't want to use tripwire hooks.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the command `/kill @a[x=-131,y=5,z=227,dx=9,dy=0,dz=9]` in a repeating command block. [Mcstacker](https://mcstacker.net/) is a great resource for advanced command generation. You can read more about the volume selector [here](https://minecraft.wiki/w/Commands#Selecting_targets_by_volume).